# Stateful widget not rebuilding child widget when state changes (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm building a form that signs up the user on Firebase, and where the ElevatedButton either displays "CREATE YOUR ACCOUNT" or a CircularProgressIndicator, based on the state of isLoading. Yet, the button's child doesn't change based on isLoading.

The states *does* change -- I'm printing out isLoading in the middle of my onPressed methode, and I do see it as *true*.

Why isn't the button changing its child?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tedy/components/custom_text_form_field.dart';
import 'package:tedy/components/custom_wrapper.dart';

class EmployerOnboardingOneView extends StatefulWidget {
  const EmployerOnboardingOneView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EmployerOnboardingOneView> createState() =>
      _EmployerOnboardingOneViewState();
}

class _EmployerOnboardingOneViewState extends State<EmployerOnboardingOneView> {
  var firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  var lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  var emailController = TextEditingController();
  var passwordController = TextEditingController();
  var passwordConfirmController = TextEditingController();

  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/tedy_logo_color.png',
            filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: CustomWrapper(
        maxWidth: 400,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Create a Tedy account for your company',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          CustomTextFormField(
              controller: firstNameController, label: 'First Name'),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          CustomTextFormField(
              controller: lastNameController, label: 'Last Name'),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          CustomTextFormField(controller: emailController, label: 'Email'),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          CustomTextFormField(
              controller: passwordController,
              isPassword: true,
              label: 'Password'),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          CustomTextFormField(
              controller: passwordConfirmController,
              isPassword: true,
              label: 'Confirm your password'),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              onPressed: () async {
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = true;
                });
                if (passwordController.text != passwordConfirmController.text) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Passwords must match'),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  try {
                    FirebaseAuth.instance
                        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email: emailController.text,
                            password: passwordController.text)
                        .then((value) {
                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          context, '/', (route) => false);
                    });
                    print(isLoading);
                  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(
                        content: Text(e.message != null
                            ? e.message as String
                            : 'There was an error.'),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                });
              },
              child: isLoading
                  ? const SizedBox(
                      width: 30,
                      height: 30,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Text('CREATE YOUR ACCOUNT'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `then` for the future. so the last  `isLoading = false;` executed when you pressed the button. You can change state inside .then instead of end. Also you can add inside `FirebaseAuthException`. make sure to remove last `isLoading = false;`

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text)
    .then((value) {
  setState(() {
    isLoading = false;
  });
  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      context, '/', (route) => false);
});
```

Comment: GLad to help, you can explore more about [async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Answer (score 1):

createUserWithEmailAndPassword is async, so you have to await it

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance
                        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email: emailController.text,
                            password: passwordController.text);
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          context, '/', (route) => false);
```

Your code set isLoading to true, does the password logic and calls this method. But since you don't await it here it just skips it and calls the setState with isLoading = false.